# sql not executing properly

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two sql files: The first one creates database, tables, and stored procedures. The second  populates created tables with 90000 entries.

The creating sql file creates a total of 1 database, 26 tables and 104 stored procedures.
The populate sql file adds 90000 entries.

For some reason when I execute the create file it works perfectly every time.

When I execute the populate file it works halfway. It populates half the tables, and the other half will stay empty. I noticed if I wait around 2 minutes after executing the create file and then try to execute the populate file then it works perfectly. Why is it doing that? Is there no way to populate tables very quickly without having to wait?

I am using the latest version of mysql and I have tried executing contents of the populate file via phpmyadming, and that yielded the same results.

Comment: It sounds as though something has a lock on your tables. Are you using transactions? In your insertion file check which table is being inserted into and post the sql used to create that table.

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko I am not using any transactions. I am inserting data by simply doing inserts, this is example of one of the smaller inserts `INSERT INTO faults (`id`, `faults_name` ) VALUES (1, 'name');` The problem is that only tabled to which I am inserting 1000+ entries do not work without the 2 minute cooldown, I tried reducing insert to smaller amount and it worked fine. The tables themselves are nothing special either, each table contains at most 7 columns.

Comment: Do you get an error message?  Is there any type of mirroring configured that could be setting up in a background thread?

Comment: @SteveWellens that is the part that makes no sense. I get no error messages, and everything always says that sql executed successfully both when I run it on phpmyadmin and through command line. For 2 minutes straight after creating of database and tables there seems to be a delay where adding 1000+ entries to a table causes them not to work.

Comment: Some sort of server cache and refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to assume that the file that creates database and tables also create `PRIMARY KEYS` and `Indexes`.  Have you considered splitting the files up into:

1. Create Database and Tables
2. Load Data
3. Create Primary Keys and Indexes
4. Create Stored Procedures.

As was also suggested try increasing the bulk_insert_buffer_size and change the way you insert from a single query as you posted to:

```
INSERT INTO faults(id, fault_name) VALUES (...), (...) ...
```

Comment: +1, OP could also benefit from running `CHECK` if he's going to implement keys and indices *after* the bulk insert. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/check-table.html

Comment: Oh wow this is AMAZING!!! It worked perfectly. How come this procedure did not cause any issues? Also thanks a lot @MatthewPK CHECK trick came in pretty handy too! Thank you very much guys, this was a lifesaver.

Comment: @Quillion The fact that you have to update the indexes and primary keys (which is also an index) while you are inserting has likely caused this to happen.  Take a look at [INSERT SPEED](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html) that would provide more details.  It is always more advantageous to create indexes after the fact as they take less storage